# ng-bootstrap datepicker validity and initial value

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

using the datepicker component in a template-driven form like so:

```
        <input
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"
          ngbDatepicker
          #from="ngbDatepicker"
          (click)="from.toggle()"
          [(ngModel)]="params.from"
          name="from"
          required
        />
```

how would I go about getting the validity? `{{from.invalid}}` doesn't return anything.

Also, how would I set the initial state? tried:

`new Date()`

```
{
  year: 2017,
  month: 10,
  day: 20
}
```

Simple string like `2017-10-20` and `20-10-2017` (matching my format).

Comment: And still not clear abt what exact date validation you are talking about, can you be more specific. :)

Comment: the validation needed is `required`, I put the attribute in the question

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4208 this link must be helpful check rythos42 comment.